# Propagating master changes to feature branch via github web interface

Tags: git, svn, github, branch, rebase

I've been an SVN user for a long time, and have used Github mostly using the fork-pull model. So now having switched to the feature-branch model, I am trying to propagate changes from master branch(somethings have changed) to feature branches. 
Now the way to do this via command line would be to

a.) Rebase

```
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase master
```

b.) checkout feature branch and merge master

```
git checkout feature-branch
git merge origin/master
```

But I am trying to do this online via github. So is it a good idea to

```
 1.) Create a pull request with base branch - Feature branch and 
compare branch - Master and commit
 2.) And then merge feature branch into the master with another pull request.
```

Essentially is this the same as doing either of the two methods above via the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a pull request merge work like a command line merge. `git checkout feature` then `git merge origin/master` will merge master into that feature.

If you create a pull request that leads to conflict, GitHub will tell you to merge it with the command line. If the branches can be automatically merged, it will be the same as doing it through the command line.

If you want to read more about how `merge` and `rebase` are different, I can recommend [this article](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/conceptual-overview) which I think is quite good.